# Need help to create component template using Template building block

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I need help with following scenario:

I have page template PT1 , which contains 2 TBBs and I have component template CT1, which contains 1 TBB.

I created a page using the Page Template(PT1) and added a component and selected the component template (CT1).

The TBBs pushing some text value to package and all three TBB are part of a single dotnet assembly and implemented in three different class, which is implementing "Itemplate" interface and implement "transform" method.

**Problem:**

In the published file i am able to see the content pushing by TBB used in Page Template PT1, but not able to see content which is pushing by TBB of Component Template CT1.

Comment: Does you CT has DWT template or just C# ? Typically, You need DWT template to output some html which is also your view. Please mentione also what type of TBB you have (C#, DWT etc..)..

Comment: I would also recommend going through this documentation : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_1C08142900B34C21AC8A86DE54C9EECC  and Debugging templates: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-159204216

Answer (score 3):

Typically, to output from a template you need to create a DWT TBB unless you are directly sending Output from C# TBB.

In your case, looks like you have all C# TBBs and are they outputting anything to the package. If not then I even doubt your PT will output any html.

You could use the Template Builder tool to debug your out of the template as in my comments the doc portal link will provide you guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently i am using only C# TBB, 2 TBBs for page template and 1 TBB for Component Template. And the output of this page after publishing will be "Js" file and those TBB are responsible to create the content of the JS file.